# Traits and generics

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I'm new to Groovy and trying Traits with generics. Here's a basic example:

```
trait MyTrait<K, V> {
    public Map<K, V> getMap() {
        new HashMap<K, V>();
    }
}

class MyTraitImpl implements MyTrait<String, String> {
}
```

This is the Java stub it generates:

```
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.K;
import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.V;

public class MyTraitImpl
        extends java.lang.Object implements
        MyTrait<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>, groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
    ;

    public groovy.lang.MetaClass getMetaClass() {
        return (groovy.lang.MetaClass) null;
    }

    public void setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass mc) {
    }

    public java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String method, java.lang.Object arguments) {
        return null;
    }

    public java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String property) {
        return null;
    }

    public void setProperty(java.lang.String property, java.lang.Object value) {
    }

    public java.util.Map<K, V> getMap() {
        return (java.util.Map<K, V>) null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it imports `javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.K` and `V` (??) and of course I get a compilation error:

```
Error:(17, 23) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class K
  location: class MyTraitImpl
```

Any way to fix this?

---

EDIT: on a clean rebuild, it doesn't import those K and V anymore, but still same problem. Here is the generated stub:

```
public class MyTraitImpl
        extends java.lang.Object implements
        MyTrait<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>, groovy.lang.GroovyObject {
    ;

    public groovy.lang.MetaClass getMetaClass() { return (groovy.lang.MetaClass) null; }

    public void setMetaClass(groovy.lang.MetaClass mc) {}

    public java.lang.Object invokeMethod(java.lang.String method, java.lang.Object arguments) { return null; }

    public java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String property) { return null; }

    public void setProperty(java.lang.String property, java.lang.Object value) {}

    public java.util.Map<K, V> getMap() { return (java.util.Map<K, V>) null; }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why it's importing `import static javafx.scene.input.KeyCode.K;`?  That's wrong..

Comment: @tim_yates No idea, it is an auto-generated stub. Not sure if the problem is from Groovy or IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I installed Groovvy 2.4.6 on the underlying OS (Ubuntu in my case) this problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Groovy has its default imports, but javafx is not one of them. Groovy is not going to take a guess and add import statements for you. So it must be IntelliJ.

The fact that K and V were not replaced with String is evidence that traits cannot be generic. In fact, when you think about it, it doesn't make sense for them to be. Unlike interfaces, traits provide an implementation; A *single* implementation which cannot account for the various ways a generic can be implemented.

Comment: Thanks, but if you see my edit after a project clean, it doesn't add those imports anymore but still same error.